# Numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In my project I use a library (`root_numpy`) which returns data as an array of arrays:

```
data = array([array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

I would like to turn this object to a regular 2d numpy array.

```
array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4],
   [5, 6]])
```

I already tried `np.vstack` but that was rather slow. Is there an efficient way to accomplish this task? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is already a regular numpy array

Comment: what operation you can't do with `data` as a regular numpy array?

Comment: could you specify what is your task with your `data` array and why you would like it the way you want it?

Comment: @user3100115 it appears to be an 1-D numpy array of dtype object, containing normal 1-D numpy arrays. That is not a regular 2-D numpy array.

Comment: I am not sure if there is anything better than `np.vstack`.

Comment: I need to sum over the second axis.  But data.sum(axis=1) raises an error: axis Entry out of bounds

Comment: @BasSwinckels `data.ndim`  yields `2` perhaps you also know that you can change `dtype` using `data=data.astype('int')` , `data.sum(axis=1)` gives  `array([3, 7, 11], dtype=object)`

Comment: If you do `from numpy import array` and then copy-paste `data = array([array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])], dtype=object)`, you get indeed a 2-dim array. But I guess the question just shows the `repr` of what the library returns. I assume that you can simulate it as `data = np.empty(3, dtype=object); data[:] = [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])]`, which has `ndim=1`. Martin, can you confirm what is `data.ndim`?

Comment: Exactly `data.ndim`  returns 1 and `data.shape` returns (3,)

Comment: @MartinB. then `np.vstack(data).sum(axis=1)` is probably the best you can do.

Comment: ok, thank you very much.

Comment: `np.array` tries to create the largest dimension array it can.  It requires some trickery to create an array of arrays - if all are the same size.    It may just be conincience that `root_numpy` is returning equal length subarrays.

Comment: Which `root_numpy` function did you use to produce this array?  Maybe a different function would give a 2d array.

Comment: i used `tree2array` on a root tree containing c++ vectors.

Comment: Sounds like it is converting the c++ arrays to numpy arrays, and packing those together in the most general array, dtype object.  They could be different size arrays.  `vstack` (`concatenate`) is probably faster than `np.array`, but both might work.

Comment: Currently im using `np.array(data.tolist()) `, which seems to be fast er than vtsack